# Python: create a dictionary with elements consist of file, path and the content

Tags: python, file, dictionary, filepath, os.walk

The issue I'm facing is that I have to find each file that ends in ".txt" and read it's content to return a dictionary.

**Returned dictionary should looks like this:**

```
dic = { 'Folder\\\fileName.txt' : "This is content" }
```

So far I have:

```
directory = os.path.join("C:/Users/John/Desktop/Ppractice") 
rootdir = directory.rstrip(os.sep)    
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):  
    folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')  
            a = f.read()  
            parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
            print dir
```

when I run the program I get `None`

Comment: You are more likely to get a response if it looks like you have attempted to solve this yourself.

Comment: As such, I think this question is too broad. You are asking for a complete solution. If you share your existing code and point out where you are having trouble, SO is an ideal place to figure out what needs improvement. Please also read: **[mcve]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
from os.path import join
def getFileContent(path_dir):
    return_Dict = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                f=open(os.path.join(root, file),'r')
                content = (f.read())
                f.close()           
                return_Dict["\\\\".join(f.name[3:].split("\\"))] = content     
    return ('{%s}' % ', '.join(['"%s": "%s"' % (k, v) for k, v in return_Dict.items()]))
dic = getFileContent(path_dir = "..\\PracPython" ) 
print (dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to modify your code a bit.
I suggest you use a recursive function for this, as you would want it to dynamically read all `"txt"` files in sub-directories as well.
Something like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

def getFileContent(path_dir, dict_In):

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path_dir):
        folders = path.split(os.sep)

        for dir in dirs:
            inner_path = path + '/' + dir
            getFileContent(inner_path, dict_In)

        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                f=open(os.path.join(path, file),'r')
                content = f.read()
                dict_In[f.name] = content


path = os.path.join("C:/Users/John/Desktop/Ppractice")
result_dict = {}
getFileContent(path_dir = path, dict_In = result_dict)
pprint(result_dict)
```

Comment: My bad, now that I re-ran with some correction, it prints `{}` 

The dir should have one txt file and subdir should have another .txt file in there with a couple of .pngs. But above, I modified my solution and gave me pretty close result so I was leaning more towards that solution. 


Question: I was wondering why you are using "pprint"?

Comment: nothing.. you can do away with it... It's just a `"pretty print"`